# Curl Error 56 "Failure when receiving data from the peer" while sending .tar.gz File

Tags: curl, compression, tar, gzip, curl-commandline

I have a problem with this CURL call:

```
curl -X POST \
     --data-binary '@File01.tar.gz' \
     http://website.intra.prova.it/gore-orgac/PINGU/TEST/lots/Test_017/content/files/File02.tar.gz
```

And I receive this error:

> curl: (56) Failure when receiving data from the peer

But if I do this CURL:

```
curl -X POST \
     --data-binary '@File01.tar.gz' \
     http://website.intra.prova.it/gore-orgac/PINGU/TEST/lots/Test_017/content/files/File02
```

Its works well.

Why is that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`cURl error 56` can have different reason like:

1. Passing data to be uploaded in URL itself instead of `POST` request
2. Probably Proxy blocking the request to the server.
3. In some cases, server do not support particular request, like some servers support `PUT/POST` any one of them.

When I received this error last time, it was proxy blocking the request to the server.

But in your case, in non working case:

```
curl -X POST \
     --data-binary '@File01.tar.gz' \
     http://website.intra.prova.it/gore-orgac/PINGU/TEST/lots/Test_017/content/files/File02.tar.gz
```

you have appended the file to be `POST` in URL itself, which is the location actually not available on server,

These can be reason not sure, it happened to me long back while playing with cURL command-line.

Comment: is there any way for get more detail logs, so we can know the error essential reason.

Comment: Use curl -v to see more information on what's happening. You can also use curl --trace-ascii <filename>for a file dump of all incoming and outgoing information. See the docs for more info: https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me because my POST data was too big.  I was doing:

```
curl -X POST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @too-big.file
```

To resolve the issue, i split the file into 2 parts with:

```
split -l 150000 too-big.file
```

Then ran 2 POSTS:

```
curl -X POST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @xaa
curl -X POST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @xab
```

Answer (score 0):

Check both ends are in secure or non-secure servers.

Answer (score -3):

Mine was related to the Parsoid Service / VisualEditor for the MediaWiki environment

sudo service parsoid restart

Fixed it in my case